# Java: Generalization possible between: streams, readers, char buffers, stringbuilder, ...?

Tags: java, string, stream, buffer, nio

### Background story:

There are these Source and Result interfaces for XML.
These are adapters between different XML technologies in Java.
Instances of these classes represent DOM, SAX, JAXB, XML streams, XML events
(and even more?).

### The question:

So, is there something comparable for plain old strings? Some generalization
between the following?

- `[Input|Output]Stream`
- `Reader|Writer`
- `StringBuffer`
- `StringBuilder`
- `CharBuffer` (from NIO)
- `File` *(or `Path` for the JDK7-fans among us)*
- (and finally) `CharSequence`

Perhaps there is some common API (Apache commons something...?) which provides such functionality?

### Clarifying example:

#### Usage with classic approach:

An interface needs to be able to read (write) characters from (to) all possible sources (results):

```
interface SomeInterface {
    readFrom(CharacterSequence source);
    readFrom(InputStream source);
    readFrom(Reader source);
    readFrom(File source);
    // ...
    writeTo(CharacterSequence result);
    writeTo(OutputStream result);
    writeTo(Writer result);
    writeTo(File result);
    // ...
}
```

#### Usage with intended approach:

With some imaginary `CharacterSource` and `CharacterResult` interfaces, read/write now possible with one method each:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    readFrom(CharacterSource source);
    writeTo(CharacterResult result);
}
```

#### Intended approach implementation, possible hierarchy:

```
interface CharacterSource
+ class CharBufferSource
+ class InputStreamSource
+ class ReaderSource
+ class FileSource
+ ...

interface CharacterResult
+ class CharBufferResult
+ class OutputStreamResult
+ class WriterResult
+ class FileResult
+ ...
```

**If such functionality is not present, should I write an own mini-API?**
*(for a larger API, I'm currently involved at)*

**What's about *this*?**

Comment: Can you explain what such an interface would look like, and why one would want to use it?

Comment: added clarifying example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [this](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) (yep - Apache Commons).

Comment: Hm, utility classes, looks litte unhandy. But thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can generalise your interface by using `Reader` and `Writer`.  If you wish to read from / write to a `File` you can use `FileReader` / `FileWriter`.  Likewise you can use other `Reader` / `Writer` implementations to read from / write to a `String` (i.e. `CharSequence`) or a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't **[Google's common-io](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/package-summary.html)**'s **[`InputSupplier`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/class-use/InputSupplier.html)** and **[`OutputSupplier`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/class-use/OutputSupplier.html)** similar things to my proposed interfaces? 
(A way to generalize all possible streams of input and output)

The strange thing is, the type parameter of Google's interfaces doesn't have any constraints (I was thinking of `Closable` or something).